# Core Data sort descriptor with NSDate, iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to filter core data objects depending on a date attribute.

This is my current code:

```
func getFetchedResultController(selectedEntity: NSString){

    let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(selectedEntity as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let date = NSDate()

    let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp < %@",date)

    let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor] //, secondSortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) {
        abort()
    }

 print(fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0)
}
```

But I get an error at line:

```
let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp < %@",date)
```

How should I change this sort descriptor to get the objects that have an older or a newer date on the "timeStamp" attribute?

Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To fetch all objects satisfying some condition you don't need a
sort descriptor but a *predicate*, for example:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timeStamp < %@", date)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

You need a *sort descriptor* to get the objects in a specified order,
for example:

```
let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
```

Comment: ¿How to change the specified order (sort descriptor) and refresh NSFetchedResultsController to show the results?

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0**
This works with no problem for me

```
let fec:NSFetchRequest = YourEntity.fetchRequest()
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "type", ascending: true)
fec.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
let items = try! context.fetch(fec)
```

Answer (score 0):

**>Swift4**

```
func getLastDateFromEntries(entityName:String) -> [NSManagedObject]{
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        let sortDescriptors = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dueDate", ascending: false) // dueDate is key
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptors]
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1 // add limit
        let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        return fetchedResults
    }
    catch {
        print ("fetch task failed", error)
        return []
    }
    
}
```