# Sort an array of run objects by date (core data)

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

In my running app, I am creating an array of run objects from core data. However, I need to sort them by date (each run object has a date variable associated with it). Here's my code:

```
func loadFromCoreData() {
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let runFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Run")
    do {
        let fetchedRuns = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(runFetch) as! [Run]
        for run in fetchedRuns {
            self.runs.append(run)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch run: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Before the function ends, how would I sort my array of run objects (called runs) by date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core Data sort descriptor with NSDate, iOS with Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511999/core-data-sort-descriptor-with-nsdate-ios-with-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that sorts the array based on your `date` attribute :

```
 func sortArrayDate(array:[Run])-> [NSManagedObject]{
        let newArray = array.sort ({
            (obj1, obj2) in
            let p1 = obj1 as Run
            let p2 = obj2 as Run
            return p1.date_attr!.compare(p2.date_attr!) == .OrderedDescending
        })
        return newArray
    }
```

and

```
enum NSComparisonResult : Int {
    case OrderedAscending
    case OrderedSame
    case OrderedDescending
}
```

Call your array:

```
sortArrayDate(self.runs)
```

to sort in descending order.